# Mysql get values from column having more than certain characters without punctuation

Tags: mysql

How can I get all the values from mysql table field, having more than 10 characters without any special characters (space, line breaks, colons, etc.)

Let's say I have table name myTable and the field I want to get values from is myColumn.

```
myColumn
--------
1234
------
123 456
------
123:456
-------
1234
5678
--------
123-456
----------------
1234567890123
```

So here I would like to get all the field values except first one i.e. 1234

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

UPDATE:

Sorry if I was unable to give proper description of my problem. I have tried it again:

- If there is count of more than 10 characters without punctuation, then retrieve that as well.
- Retrieve all the values which have special characters like line break, spaces, etc.
- Yes, I have primary key in this table if this helps.

Comment: Your question is conflicting - you ask for:  values with more than 10 characters and NO special characters, but you say the query should return : "123 456" (only seven characters and has a space)

Comment: Do you have an id column in your table, so we could exclude the first row by id?

Comment: Do you mean "count the characters that are not special, and if there are at least 10 return it"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic seems to be "more than 10 characters OR has special punctuation":

```
where length(mycol) > 10 or
      mycol regexp '[^a-zA-Z0-9]'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MyColumn
From MyTable
WHERE MyColumn RLIKE '([a-z0-9].*){10}'
```

- `[a-z0-9]` matches a normal character.
- `([a-z0-9].*)` matches a normal character followed by anything.
- `{10}` matches the preceding regexp 10 times.

The result is that this matches 10 normal characters with anything between them.

Comment: do you how to exclude line break values?